# PWA module in nuxt.js doesn't work on iOS and safari

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I was trying to use PWA module in nuxt.js, so far I launched nuxt app on firebase server on this address below.

https://quasar-d56d0.firebaseapp.com/

On chrome for android, windows and mac works well but it doesn't work on iOS, and for safari doesn't work at all for any device.

Below is my nuxt.config.js.

As well, I want to ask, is there any option to make custom popping-out window asking user to download nuxt app, as a progressive web app, instead of using this in chrome?

```
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
},
  /*
  ** Overwrite's generated manifest values
  */
  manifest: {
    name: 'Nuxt.js PWA',
    short_name: 'Nuxt.js PWA',
    lang: 'en',
    display: 'standalone',
  },
  pwa: {
    meta: {
      mobileAppIOS: true 
    }
  }
}
```